# QuickBooks Desktop CustomerModRq ShipToAddress Unrecoverable Error

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I am using accessing QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise 2016 with QBFC SDK version 12.  I am using a qbXML file with the SDKTestPlust3 application.  I modified the QBW.INI file with the following entries but it didn't seem to help any. I have run Utilities | Rebuild Data with no reported issues.

```
[DBSERVEROPTIONS]
InitialCache=512
MaxCache=0
```

The CustomerModRq causes QuickBooks to crash with an unrecoverable error after which it terminates.  The CustomerModRq causes this error on an intermittent basis but degrades until it happens every time and I have to reboot the machine to get back to some successes.  The ShipToAddress Name value is correct and the EditSequence value is updated appropriately every time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError">
<CustomerModRq requestID = "0">
<CustomerMod>
<ListID>8000000A-1308669896</ListID>
<EditSequence>1471365900</EditSequence>
<ShipToAddress>
<Name>Ship To 1210</Name>
<Addr1>My Data</Addr1>
<Addr2>My Data</Addr2>
<City>My Data</City>
<State>FL</State>
<PostalCode>32259</PostalCode>
<DefaultShipTo>1</DefaultShipTo>
</ShipToAddress>
</CustomerMod>
</CustomerModRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Here is a copy of the qbsdklog.txt

```
20160816.124931 I   3760    RequestProcessor    ========= Started Connection =========
20160816.124931 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Request Processor, QBXMLRP2 v13.0
20160816.124931 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Connection opened by app named 'SDKTest Plus 3'
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Begin Session started...
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Current Process is elevated
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Current User is in AdminGroup
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Current Process is ran as Admin
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Current Process Integrity Level : 3000
20160816.124933 V   3760    RequestProcessor    Not in-proc request.
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    File info: no file provided.
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Getting an instance of pRunningInfo using pRunningInstanceFinder 
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    GetmajorVersion
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    GetReleaseNumber
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Getflavor
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    GetdataFileVersion
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    There is a running version of QuickBooks: v26.0R7 (2607), belprofessional, bel_stratum
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Starting QuickBooks (no launch)
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Performing QB Launch Retries
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Check QB process ID before calling instance finder to find it.
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Process Found -> 4428 for Current User -> Phil
20160816.124933 V   3760    RequestProcessor    QBW32.exe Proc Id: 4428
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Getting the IUnknown COM instance of QB
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Obtained the IUnknown COM instance of QB without an exception
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    QuickBooks launch succeeded.
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    get_CompanyFileIsOpen call successful
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Check if the requested company file is already open.
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    yes. It is open.
20160816.124933 I   3760    RequestProcessor    Opening the file in the DoNotCare mode.
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Attempt getting the Request Processor interface
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc2
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc3
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc4
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Got query interface pointer till pReqProc5
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Calling raw_SDKOpenFile4
20160816.124933 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Successfully opened the data file: C:\Temp\My Data.QBW
20160816.124935 D   3760    RequestProcessor    COM access to QuickBooks starting ...
20160816.124935 I   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'SDKTest Plus 3' starting requests (process 3760).

20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest ===============================================
20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest Begin dumping request data received from client
20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest ===============================================
20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="12.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError"><CustomerModRq requestID = "0"><CustomerMod><ListID>8000000A-1308669896</ListID><EditSequence>1471365900</EditSequence><ShipToAddress><Name>Ship To 1210</Name><Addr1>My Data</Addr1><Addr2>My Data</Addr2><City>My Data</City><State>FL</State><PostalCode>32259</PostalCode><DefaultShipTo>1</DefaultShipTo></ShipToAddress></CustomerMod></CustomerModRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest ================================================
20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest End dumping of request data received from client
20160816.124935 V   4428    QBSDKProcessRequest ================================================

20160816.124935 D   4428    MacroManager::DumpMacroMap  Map contains no entries
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXParseManager   Using Xerces-c parser, version 2_5_0
20160816.124935 V   4428    XMLDtdMapper    TransformProcessingInstruction using DOCTYPE: <!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 12.0//EN' 'http://developer.intuit.com'>

20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving public ID: -//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 12.0//EN
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver qbxmlops120.dtd
20160816.124935 V   4428    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxmlops120.dtd
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving Public Entity took 0.0150 seconds
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving system ID: qbxml120.dtd
20160816.124935 V   4428    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxml120.dtd
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving System Entity took 0.0000 seconds
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving system ID: qbxmlso120.dtd
20160816.124935 V   4428    ParseManager    Getting SDKResource: qbxmlso120.dtd
20160816.124935 V   4428    XercesSAXEntityResolver Resolving System Entity took 0.0000 seconds
20160816.124935 D   4428    QBXMLMsgs   CustomerModRq
20160816.124935 I   4428    SpecVersion Current version of qbXML in use: 12.0
20160816.124935 D   4428    MsgSetHandler   Parsing took 0.0470 seconds
20160816.124935 I   4428    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  MODIFY: Customer Job
20160816.124935 E   4428    StorageInterface    *** UNKNOWN EXCEPTION THROWN WHEN PROCESSING THE MOD REQUEST ***. This is an indication of a possible internal QuickBooks error.
20160816.124949 E   3760    RequestProcessor    Process Request error = 800706be
20160816.124949 D   3760    RequestProcessor    Processing requests took 13.970 seconds.
```

I will follow up with a support request.  FYI, this is the same company file in another support request with the large number of Ship To Addresses under the top level Customer.

Best Regards